# swift image for row action buttons

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

In my swift 2 app, I have a table view and a row action button (delete),
I found a way to change the background color of this button, but now I would like to set an image instead of the text "Delete"

Is there an swift solution?
here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

    // do some action

    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return [delete]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This extension of UIColor will accomplish your goal. You will have to play with the size depending on your image.

```
extension UIColor {
 static func imageWithBackgroundColor(image: UIImage, bgColor: UIColor) -> UIColor {
    let size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()


    let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, bgColor.CGColor)
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, .Fill)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rectangle, image.CGImage)

    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

   return UIColor(patternImage: img)

  }
}
```

To Use:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
  let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

 // do some action
// 
 if let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "myImage") { 
 delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.imageWithBackgroundColor(image: buttonImage, bgColor: UIColor.blueColor()) 
  }
return [delete]
}
```

Comment: yes, this i tried too. but i use the parameter backgroundColor to change the background color. how can i set the backgroundColor AND the Image? or i can make an image with background color. but which size should I set for this image

Comment: thx, i putted this extension into my class. but how can i apply this to my delete button?

Comment: PERFECT ! but now i have the next problem. how can i center the image vertical and horizontal and with image repeating

Comment: You may need to apply a transform (rotation) on the context before drawing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: yourImage), forState: .Normal)
```

be sure to set the button to 'Custom' in the Attributes Inspector and also delete the text.

Comment: i can't set it to custom. this not a normal button. I talking about the "buttons" which will be get visible, if you swipe from right to left above a row

Comment: Sorry about that. I checked the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewRowAction/style) and didn't see anything about adding images. Could you create a custom font with the image and import it into the project?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this   https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell . Hope this help